# How to get the frame numbers that are dropped when changing the frame rate using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that plays at 30fps. I changed the frame rate to 20fps by using the command
`ffmpeg -i lamp02_20210212_060804-compressed.mp4 -filter:v fps=20 xx.mp4`. But I want to get the frame numbers of the dropped frames. I saw here [Which frame does ffmpeg get when reducing the frame rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555771/which-frame-does-ffmpeg-get-when-reducing-the-frame-rate) that you can get the frame but I require only the frame number. Is it possible to do this and if yes, how? Any pointers in the right direction will be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump the debug logs and examine those.

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf fps=20 -an -f null - -v debug 2>&1 | grep Parsed_fps
```

The output will have lines of the form,

```
[Parsed_fps_0 @ 000002619a56bd40] Read frame with in pts 11264, out pts 15
[Parsed_fps_0 @ 000002619a56bd40] Writing frame with pts 14 to pts 14
[Parsed_fps_0 @ 000002619a56bd40] Read frame with in pts 11776, out pts 15
[Parsed_fps_0 @ 000002619a56bd40] Dropping frame with pts 15
[Parsed_fps_0 @ 000002619a56bd40] Read frame with in pts 12288, out pts 16
[Parsed_fps_0 @ 000002619a56bd40] Writing frame with pts 15 to pts 15
```

All the pts are denominated in terms of a [timebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43333542/). The timebase of `in pts` is the reciprocal of the input stream's tbn value. The timebase of `out pts` is the reciprocal of the filter's output fps.

Trace the `in pts` for the frames which show `Dropping frame with pts ..` and get their timestamp values.